# Google play services simple chat implementation?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am looking to create an extremely simple chat feature for my app.

I just want to be able to send a message to the opponent in my Turn-Based Multiplayer match.

I don't want to use libraries like Scringo and what have you. Is there any way to implement this?

I've tried to use `Games.RealtimeMultiplayer.sendReliableMessage()` but my players aren't in a room so it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In looking through the API, it appears that the only way to send out data is to call takeTurn

> To take a turn, use this method:
>
> Method    Description
>   takeTurn()
>
> Your game should only invoke this method when it is the user's turn in an active turn-based match. After invoking this method, the user sees this match under the Their Turn list in the match list UI.
>   If a participant ID is specified in the method call, that participant becomes the current player and can play a turn. The first time this happens to an invited player, the player receives an invitation notification. Subsequently, the player receives a turn notification.
>   If no pending participant ID is specified, the match state changes to MATCH_STATUS_AUTO_MATCHING. Your game can only leave the participant ID unspecified if there are player slots that are still vacant for auto-matching.
>   Your game can call takeTurn() with the current player as the pending participant. In this case, Play Games services uploads the the game data but no notification is sent.

There are no other calls that change the data that is held in the servers and passed to the other player(s).

Now, having said that, it IS possible to send out a chat for the player that currently owns the Turn.  It would appear that there are two ways to do that, either include the Chat and set the Pending Participant to the Next Participant... or update only the Chat portion, and then call takeTurn with the Pending Participant set to the currently active Participant.  Looking at the documentation, this would then update the Data held on Google's servers, BUT, would not necessarily send out any notification that it had updated, as it appears that Notifications are only sent out if it is actually to notify a Player that it is their turn. (if you envision your app as being open while the Player waited for others to complete, then it could poll for the data using getData(), as there is no requirement that I can see for it to be a Player's turn to request the Data().

This would allow a player to Chat, but not Real Time like you mention... as the API is strictly turn based.

Comment: You are talking about the Turn-based Multiplayer API. He is specifically referencing the Realtime Multiplayer, which has a method called sendReliableMessage. Shouldn't it be possible to use the Turn-based one for the game data but the Realtime one for chat?